# Liferay Search - PermissionChecker

Tags: search, liferay, liferay-6

Can I disable permission check on the search results? When I saw the BaseIndexer.java, it is doing the following thing.

```
PermissionChecker permissionChecker =
            PermissionThreadLocal.getPermissionChecker();

        int start = searchContext.getStart();
        int end = searchContext.getEnd();

        if (isFilterSearch() && (permissionChecker != null)) {
            searchContext.setStart(0);
            searchContext.setEnd(end + INDEX_FILTER_SEARCH_LIMIT);
        }

        Hits hits = SearchEngineUtil.search(searchContext, fullQuery);

        searchContext.setStart(start);
        searchContext.setEnd(end);

        if (isFilterSearch() && (permissionChecker != null)) {
            hits = filterSearch(hits, permissionChecker, searchContext);
        }
```

isFilterSearch() method :

```
    protected boolean isFilterSearch() {
    return _FILTER_SEARCH;
}
```

and _FILTER_SEARCH variable :

```
private static final boolean _FILTER_SEARCH = false;
```

Modifying this class to not check permissions is the only option? Any better ideas to do this. Reason I want to do this is, More the search results it is taking time to check permissions on all of the search results. which is a bottleneck in our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe crazy idea, but you can temporally disable the permission checker:

```
PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionThreadLocal.getPermissionChecker();
PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(null);

//Search

PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);
```